# Update Storyboard UI After Retrieving Contacts

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an app that will start out by requesting access to the users contacts and then display information about the first contact in the UI.

```
    func requestContactsAccess() {
    let store = CNContactStore()
    store.requestAccess(for: .contacts, completionHandler: {_,_ in })
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let authorizationStatus = CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts)
        
        if authorizationStatus == .authorized {
            self.retrieveContacts()
            self.updateScreen()
        } else {
            self.alert()
        }
    }
```

The problem I am running into is that the UI tries to update before the app gets user permission to access the contacts. I tried to get around this by using a completion handler to call the function to update the UI after fetching the contacts but this causes the error when updating my label "UILabel.text must be used from main thread only"

TLDR: How can I ensure I have retrieved the device contacts before updating the UI?

Comment: Don't post codes as screenshot

Comment: Put the whole `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` block into the completion handler

Answer (score 1):

@RickyMo 's answer was what fixed it for me.

Solution:

```
    func requestContactsAccess() {
    let store = CNContactStore()
    store.requestAccess(for: .contacts, completionHandler: {_,_ in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let authorizationStatus = CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts)
            
            if authorizationStatus == .authorized {
                self.retrieveContacts()
                self.updateScreen()
            } else {
                self.alert()
            }
        }
    })
}
```